React component re-rendering issue with redux-toolkit
I created a component
const Audit = () => {
    let auditReducer = useSelector((state: State) => state?.auditReducer);
    let [isDataGridLoading, setIsDataGridLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            setId('some id')
            setLoading(false);
        }
        try {
            getData();
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error in Audit', err);
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        let setDataAndGrid = async () => {
            // transformedData
            setIsDataGridLoading(true);
            await setDataGridDataAndConfig(auditReducer.id, sheet);
            setIsDataGridLoading(false);
        }
        if (auditReducer.id!=null) setDataAndGrid();
    }, [auditReducer?.id, currentSheet?.idx])


    return (
        <div>
            {isDataGridLoading === false
                ? <InterimLeftPane />
                : <Loading />
            }
            </div>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Audit;

And I have created a reducer auditReducer which maintains id and its setter function setId.
Now my question is in my first useEffect I use setId() to change the id, and in 2nd reducer I have kept that id as a dependency.
Now after execution of first useEffect and setting of i, I expected 2nd useEffect to be triggered but that disnt happen. Why? Am I doing something wrong?
auditReducer
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export interface IFAudit {
  gridData: any,
  id: string | null
}

export const initialState: IFAudit = {
  gridData: [],
  id: null
}

const audit = createSlice({
  name: 'audit',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: () => initialState, // clear state on unmount of component
    setGridData: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.gridData = payload
    },
    setId: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.id = payload
    },
  }
})

export const { setGridData, setId } = audit.actions

export default audit.reducer


What is setId? Is that some action that needs to me dispatched to the Redux store to effect a state update? Please [edit] to clarify the problem and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

I mentioned after the code that setId is the setter function and that i created a reducer which maintains the state of 'id', I'll add its code in the xample as well.

Ah, then you need to dispatch the action then, e.g. dispatch(setId('some id')).

my bad, such silly mistake and i was scratching my head from last one hour

No worries, it happens to all of us at one point or another. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

thanks @DrewReese, will close the question
